# Происхождение устойчивого выражения

Tags: синтаксис

Интересно, почему так построена фраза "***самый что ни на есть***"?

Comment: Действительно, интересно!)))) Особенно интересно, к чему относится "на".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А.А.Зализняк в книге "Слово о полку Игореве": взгляд лингвиста. М., 2008.объясняет появление фраз "что ни на есть","какой ни на есть" и т.д. как остаток свободного употребления частицы НЪ в др.-р. языке (и усилительная, и отрицательная, и уступительная) и параллелизмом частиц нъ-на-но-ни.

Первоначально "ни на" было таким же соединением близких по значению частиц, как, например, "же ведь" во фразах типа "Я же ведь этого не знал". В говорах круг такого рода реликтов шире: ср. -набудь частица "-нибудь" Олон. (СРHГ, 19:137), -нинабудь частица "-нибудь" Вят., Арх., Перм., Том. (СРHГ, 21:236), гдé-набудь и гдé-нинабудь "где-то, где-нибудь", гдé-нато (в роли подтверждающей частицы; Арханг. обл. слов., 9:59), также áжнак "так что, даже" (с дополнительным -к из -ко)

Так что НА здесь не предлог, а вторая усилительная частица, проклитика к глаголу есть: что ни (на) есть . ЧТО НИ - усиление,а НА- усиление усиления, т.е. "самый-самый из всех, что есть".

http://inslav.ru/images/stories/pdf/2008_Zalizniak_Slovo_o_polku_Igoreve_vzglyad_lingvista_(3-e_izd).pdf

(Параллелизм частиц нъ и ни § 4.на стр.274)

Answer (score 0):

Существуют два варианта этого выражения: **самый что ни на есть и "самый что ни есть"**

1) Это вопрос самый что ни на есть актуальный. Момент выдался самый что ни на есть неудачный.

2) Вон цветок… самый что ни есть плохонький, а глядишь на него ― сердце радуется».

**Самый что ни есть** - это "самый, из того, что есть", усилительная частица НИ. А вот что означает предлог НА, который хотя обязательным не является, но при этом усиливает значение всего выражения.

В качестве версии можно предположить, что предлог НА направляет наше внимание на то, что есть "в **на**личии", имеется **на** выбор", предлог НА **как бы задает тему выбора**  из того, что  есть **на**лицо - "**на** есть".

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

В современном языке выделяется **частица НА**,  но при этом она имеет значение "возьми, бери". В то же время  в выражении "на, возьми" уже проявляется её усилительный характер.
А вот приставка НА в наречиях с повтором уже напрямую указывает на усиление, обозначая высшую, предельную степень какого-л. признака: крепко-накрепко строго-настрого (ударение падает на приставку).

Аналогично: **что ни есть - что ни на есть**, здесь усиление относится уже к глаголу.